# jQuery loading data to page before css is loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, node.js

I'm a complete newb in nodeJS, javascript and CSS. I'm currently writing a single-page application. I've added to my client side
a javascript file that contains several functions that retrieve data from the server.

In the head section of the HTML, I first load the css files and then the js file like so

```
<head>
    ...    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="...">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="...">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>        
    <!-- ajax functions script -->
    <script src="js/ajaxFunctions.js"></script>
</head>
```

Then, in my html, at some point, I call one of the functions in the ajaxFunctions.js like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">populatePostsList()</script>
```

Now, the function works and retrieves the data but for some reason, when working in chrome (and chrome canary) the information is presented without the CSS styling. I have no idea why this is happening. Also, when I check it in safari it actually does work but 10% of the time, it goes back to regular html with no styling.

Has anyone ever encountered this kind of problem and can direct me in the right way? 
Also, is this the best way to go about using ajax? How can I implement it so I won't
have to call the actual function but it will get called automatically when the page is first loaded?

Thanks!

I'm adding here a snippet of the populatePostsList() function.

```
function populatePostsList() {
    var counter = 1;
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.get(URLAddress + '/getPosts', {} ,function(data) {                
            var arr = data;
            for(var i = arr.Posts.length - 1 ; i >= 0 ; i--) {
                var post = arr.Posts[i];
                $('#newPosts').append(// appending fields from post // );
        });
    });    
}
```

Comment: This may have something to do with jQuery-mobile.  I know they have their own sort of `ajax` handling to make the framework gracefully handle heavy load on mobile.  You might look into their list refresh command which i think you may need to call after updating the data.  http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.2.0/docs/lists/docs-lists.html  It goes something like `$('#newPosts').refresh()` which you'd probably call in the `complete` or `success` Ajax callback.

Comment: If it is showing with the CSS rules not applied, then I can think of three possibilities.  You will need to eliminate each of these: 1) There is some sort of networking issue in properly loading the CSS, 2) There is some sort of error in your HTML which causes the browser to have a problem applying styles properly (open tags can really confuse the DOM hierarchy which can affect how styles are applied) or 3) The data you are appending has some issues with it which causes malformed or undesirably formed content.

Comment: you might be able to do something like delay the data being loaded

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/delay/

Comment: something like `$.get(URLAddress + '/getPosts', {} ,function(data) {                
            var arr = data;
            for(var i = arr.Posts.length - 1 ; i >= 0 ; i--) {
                var post = arr.Posts[i];
                $('#newPosts').append(// appending fields from post // );
        }).delay(800);` perhaps?

Comment: you can finetune the delay based on how long it takes the css to load

Comment: i would just do it with a few minutes of trial and error.

Comment: i just noticed you have `$(document).ready` inside your function - i dont think this is correct

Comment: you most likely want something like `$(document).ready(function() { function populatePostsList() {
    var counter = 1;
    
        $.get(URLAddress + '/getPosts', {} ,function(data) {                
            var arr = data;
            for(var i = arr.Posts.length - 1 ; i >= 0 ; i--) {
                var post = arr.Posts[i];
                $('#newPosts').append(// appending fields from post // );
        }); } 
    });`

Comment: wherever you have your javascript

Comment: in your script call you want `<script type="text/javascript">$(document).ready(function() { populatePostsList() })</script>` - and where you have your javascript you just need `function populatePostsList() {
    var counter = 1;
    
        $.get(URLAddress + '/getPosts', {} ,function(data) {                
            var arr = data;
            for(var i = arr.Posts.length - 1 ; i >= 0 ; i--) {
                var post = arr.Posts[i];
                $('#newPosts').append(// appending fields from post // );
        });
}`

Comment: for delay...you could do `<script type="text/javascript">$(document).ready(function() { populatePostsList().delay(800) })</script>` i believe

Comment: or you might be able to put the delay after the get request call like i said before.

Comment: let me know if you want to chat - i can walk you through it.

Comment: oh - i see you might not want delay at all - but you should change the `<script>` section in your html to look like what I said - and remove `$(document).ready` from your function (because it is being called in the <script></script> like it should) - that might solve your issue because you might be confusing your browser by calling `$(document).ready` inside the function call.

Comment: Thank you all for your help!

Apparently, the problem is in chrome. The browser chooses to user the regular plain link style instead of my css file, while safari is using my css file. After a few tweaks and changes I managed to get it working.